# Unity UI: Can you both anchor to a specific point, and stretch in all directions?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, game-engine

What I want to do is anchor a UI element to the right side of another, whilst also having its size remain relative in both X and Y with the parent object.

The closest I can get is anchoring to the right and scaling in the Y, but then the UI ends up looking stretched when the resolution changes. I'm assuming I'm missing something somewhere as it seems like a feature that would exist somewhere.

Comment: Have you looked into [`HorizontalLayoutGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/script-HorizontalLayoutGroup.html)?

Comment: @derHugo I have not, but at a glance it looks like it might be exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

try to click on the text object-> on the inspector click on the stretch - > and then on shift + alt

I hope that is what you are looking for..
[image]